# How to make arithmetic function continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, continuity, spline, arithmetic-functions

Suppose that we have an arithmetic function $f(x)$ defined as follows:

[image: A custom arithmetic function]

What are the methods in the literature that will make this function continuous and differentiable? However, it should be noted that this function can be custom. I want a function $g(x)$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ when x is integer, and g(x) must be continuos and differentiable.

Comment: For any finite number of points you can use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: Your last three points are $(5,7)$, $(5,7)$ and again $(5,7)$, shouldn't that be $(5,7)$ $(6,7)$ and $(7,4)$?

Comment: @Dominique yes you're right. I should fix thsi. but it is not important because it was just an example.

Comment: You can make a polynomial, having those values, but I believe you are more likely looking for so-called splines. I added the corresponding tag.